# Fern Wifi Cracker dont work

Tags: kali-linux, plugins, code

I cant install the Wifi Cracker in Kali Linux.
When I wanna start the Cracker this messages shows up:
(Many people have the problem but none of the proposed solutions worked for me)

```
└─$ sudo fern-wifi-cracker
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: You need to :   sudo apt install fern-wifi-cracker   ......  Then you need the following dependencies:   aircrack-ng  macchanger  python3  python3-pyqt5 python3-scapy  reaver   subversion  xterm | x-terminal-emulator    .......  https://www.kali.org/tools/fern-wifi-cracker/   ...  Did you do all this?  If so I am not sure about any future steps

Comment: I get every program which subversion do you have subversionphyton3 or just the subversion?

Comment: I rebuilt the Kali machine where I tried Fern Wifi Cracker just over a year ago. I cannot recall which subversion at the time, but the basic steps (different article) worked back then.   Basic Fern comes with Kali and it is working here. Kali 2023.3

Comment: If you have continued issues, you might try backing up any data and rebuild Kali to the newest version. Fern will be there.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked 3 Kali machines:  1 long term rolling, 1 fresh, one about a year old.

In all cases, Fern WiFi cracker is working as part of the Kali installation.

If you cannot install it using the dependencies you need, then back up any data and do a fresh install of Kali 2023.3.  Assuming you accept the default packages at installation, Fern will come included.